# How worker threads works in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, worker-thread

> Nodejs can not have a built-in thread API like java and .net
>   do.  If threads are added, the nature of the language itself will
>   change. It’s not possible to add threads as a new set of available
>   classes or functions.

Nodejs 10.x added worker threads as an experiment and now stable since 12.x. I have gone through the few blogs but did not understand much maybe due to lack of knowledge. How are they different than the threads.

Answer (score 14):

Worker threads in Javascript are somewhat analogous to WebWorkers in the browser.   They do not share direct access to any variables with the main thread or with each other and the only way they communicate with the main thread is via messaging.  This messaging is synchronized through the event loop.  This avoids all the classic race conditions that multiple threads have trying to access the same variables because two separate threads can't access the same variables in node.js. Each thread has its own set of variables and the only way to influence another thread's variables is to send it a message and ask it to modify its own variables.  Since that message is synchronized through that thread's event queue, there's no risk of classic race conditions in accessing variables.

Java threads, on the other hand, are similar to C++ or native threads in that they share access to the same variables and the threads are freely timesliced so right in the middle of functionA running in threadA, execution could be interrupted and functionB running in threadB could run.  Since both can freely access the same variables, there are all sorts of race conditions possible unless one manually uses thread synchronization tools (such as mutexes) to coordinate and protect all access to shared variables.  This type of programming is often the source of very hard to find and next-to-impossible to reliably reproduce concurrency bugs.  While powerful and useful for some system-level things or more real-time-ish code, it's very easy for anyone but a very senior and experienced developer to make costly concurrency mistakes.   And, it's very hard to devise a test that will tell you if it's really stable under all types of load or not.

node.js attempts to avoid the classic concurrency bugs by separating the threads into their own variable space and forcing all communication between them to be synchronized via the event queue. This means that threadA/functionA is never arbitrarily interrupted and some other code in your process changes some shared variables it was accessing while it wasn't looking.

node.js also has a backstop that it can run a child_process that can be written in any language and can use native threads if needed or one can actually hook native code and real system level threads right into node.js using the add-on SDK (and it communicates with node.js Javascript through the SDK interface). And, in fact, a number of node.js built-in libraries do exactly this to surface functionality that requires that level of access to the nodejs environment.  For example, the implementation of file  access uses a pool of native threads to carry out file operations.

---

So, with all that said, there are still some types of race conditions that can occur and this has to do with access to outside resources.  For example if two threads or processes are both trying to do their own thing and write to the same file, they can clearly conflict with each other and create problems.

So, using Workers in node.js still has to be aware of concurrency issues when accessing outside resources.  node.js protects the local variable environment for each Worker, but can't do anything about contention among outside resources.  In that regard, node.js Workers have the same issues as Java threads and the programmer has to code for that (exclusive file access, file locks, separate files for each Worker, using a database to manage the concurrency for storage, etc...).

Comment: Worker threads can share memory via `SHARE_ENV`, in which case all bets are off :)

Comment: @DaveNewton - `SHARE_ENV` is only  for environment variables, not for all Javascript variables and yes, then all bets are off for concurrency management of those environment variables.   There are also ways to "send" variables from one thread to another as a means of transferring ownership and access.

Answer (score 0):

It comes under the node js architecture. whenever a req reaches the node it is passed on to "EVENT QUE" then to "Event Loop" . Here the event-loop checks whether the request is 'blocking io or non-blocking io'. (blocking io - the operations which takes time to complete eg:fetching a data from someother place ) . Then Event-loop passes the blocking io to THREAD POOL. Thread pool is a collection of WORKER THREADS. This blocking io gets attached to one of the worker-threads and it begins to perform its operation(eg: fetching data from database) after the completion it is send back to event loop and later to Execution.[image]