# How can we make NodeJS multi threaded?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, asynchronous

As we know that NodeJS is single threaded asynchronous language. Is it possible to make it multi threaded language?

Comment: Use the benefits of cluster and child processes in node js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How worker threads works in Nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361858/how-worker-threads-works-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

Node JS is strictly single-threaded, you can run multiple copies of the same application and then use interprocess communication (IPC) to communicate between different processes of it.

More description can be found here about why is it single-threaded

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17959746/601182